# boost::asio::async_write() versus boost::asio::write()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Is there any advantage in terms of the time it takes to get the data buffer out onto the wire
if you use

```
boost::asio::write(m_socket, asio::buffer(dataOut_, len), asio::transfer_all());
```

instead of

```
boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(hbs, sizeof(hbs)),
                         boost::bind(&Client::handle_pulse, this,
                         boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                         boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is that the normal `write` can block until all is written, while `async_write` returns immediately and calls a callback when either all data is written or an error occurs.

I doubt there is any noticeable difference in time from call to the data actually being sent over the wire.

Comment: Thanks, that's a relief to know.